Unity Android - Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\ManagedStripped failed with output - UnityLinker.exe
When I try to build the project, I receive the following error:
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\ManagedStripped failed with output:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.18f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe @Library\Bee\artifacts\rsp\3806029852383503544.rsp
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.ParseArgumentsNormalMode(LinkRequest linkerOptions, UnityPipeline p, UnityLinkContext context, ArrayList custom_steps, Boolean usingCustomLogger, I18nAssemblies& assemblies)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(UnityLinkContext context, UnityPipeline p, LinkRequest linkerOptions, TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, ILogger customLogger)
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling()
   at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Is there a workaround ?
I have tried to change the C++ Compiler Configuration from Master to Release and to Debug. Nothing seems to work.
Thank you

It's not a full log of build. When an application is building there are several different opperations executed. You sent only the summary of those opperations. You have to look for any errors that were before this exception.
